# VBA Code to prompt user to make a selection

Tags: vba, ms-access, beforeupdate

I have some VBA code that asks a user if they wish to save a record before they close out of a form in MS Access. This is what the code looks like:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)


   Dim ctl As Control

   On Error GoTo Err_BeforeUpdate


   If Me.Dirty Then

      If MsgBox("Do you want to save?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
              "Save Record") = vbNo Then
         Me.Undo
      End If
   End If

Exit_BeforeUpdate:
   Exit Sub

Err_BeforeUpdate:
   MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
   Resume Exit_BeforeUpdate
End Sub
```

I would also like to add another message box right after the above, that asks the user if they want to "Copy the record to the Analysis & Support Table?". If yes, than I want the code to run the saved query called "Insert_Query". If no, then go to a new record.

I have very little experience when it comes to coding VBA, hence the need for assistance.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the message to appear only if they say yes to save the record then

```
If MsgBox("Do you want to save?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Save Record") = vbNo Then
    Me.Undo
Else
    If MsgBox("Copy the record to the Analysis & Support Table?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Copy Record") = vbYes Then
        CurrentDb.Execute("Insert_Query")
    Else
        'go to new record
    end if
End If
```

If you want the message to appear regardless of the selection of the first message box then

```
If MsgBox("Do you want to save?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Save Record") = vbNo Then
    Me.Undo
End If
If MsgBox("Copy the record to the Analysis & Support Table?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Copy Record") = vbYes Then
    CurrentDb.Execute("Insert_Query")
Else
    'go to new record
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for breaking the 2 up. It actually made more sense for me to choose the first option. I have run it...and everything seems to work. But it seems to ask if i want to save twice? any idea how to fix that?

Comment: The `MsgBox` with `"Do you want to save?"` shows up twice? or 2 different `MsgBox` because the latter is intended.

Comment: The `MsgBox` with `"Do you want to save?"` pops up, than i hit save, than it pops up again...

Comment: To test, place a few `Debug.Print` statements or use the debugger to step through and see at what point its repeating. i.e. if entire function is repeating or just a specific part.

Comment: If you're doing Me.Undo, I believe that will re-fire the Form_BeforeUpdate function because you're updating the form data.  Might need to put it into a different function.

Comment: @a shareef the `debug.print` doesnt do anything when i place it in the code @JohnnyBones what function would i use?